# Django error on admin site entry when deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have had success in the past hosting a website using the django-heroku package outlined [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration), but now when I try to run just a basic shell of a Django project as the start of a new project I am hit with the following error message:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://hockamer2018.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-                
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 85
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.6
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

It runs fine when I run this locally so I must have forgotten to set up something on the database on Heroku. I have thoroughly researched this question and all of the fixes seem to be to run
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
but I have done that through the heroku remote ssh and "heroku run" command both to no avail.

I am running a completely fresh Django installation where all I have done is added the two django-heroku lines to settings.py. I have tried this on both django-2.0.8 and 2.1.

Comment: "It runs fine when I run this locally so I must have forgotten to set up something on the database on Heroku."—yep, that's probably what happened. Have you run your migrations on Heroku? (Note that you _shouldn't_ run `makemigrations` on Heroku. This creates _new_ migrations and should only be done in development, when you intend to change your database. That will generate migration files that need to be committed and pushed to Heroku. But you _should_ run `migrate`, which runs the migrations against your database.)

Comment: Awesome thank-you, this was my problem I tried running just migrate and it worked this time.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished battling with this problem and I figured out that there are some operation that you have to do through the heroku cli especially when it comes to your database,

Firstly, you want to ensure that your requirements.txt is up to date so that any field in your models that is dependent on any of the third-party apps can be made (e.g models.ImageField depends on pillow).

Run the following and make sure that when committing changes, it detects the change in your migrations if any were made :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push heroku master

heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

The last two lines of code are responsible for solving your problem. My guess is that, heroku by default doesn't track the changes made to your db.sqlite (as defined in .gitignore) so it doesn't run the migrate line so you need to do that manually so when you deploy it doesn't detect the tables you've created afterwards. Hope this helps you though.